# How to manage my nested Level Data so that a singleton Level Manager can easily increment through Levels

Tags: unity

I'm making a singleton Level Manager for my Unity word game, and not sure how to structure the data/code.

In my game, there are word puzzles organized into a 4-level organizational structure:

- Realms (there are 6 realms)
- Areas (there are 5 areas in the first realm)
- Levels (there are 8 levels in the first Area)
- Words (there are 12 Word puzzles in the first level)

I have Scriptable Objects for each level in the organizational structure, and everything is very easy to manage and intuitive.  This is especially important, as others may end up designing and adding the Word Puzzles.

Now I'm programming a Level Manager singleton.  I will start the user in Realm 1, Area 1, Level 1, Word 1... and if they finish it, they can go on to the next Word (Realm 1, Area 1, Level 1, Word 2)... etc.

If all the Words were organized in a single flat table, the Level Manager singleton would be trivial.  I could just have a Word Number for each word, and increment it by one upon successful completion of the Word Puzzle.

But since my Words are organized into this nested organizational structure, I have to loop through all 4 tiers of the organizational structure in order to find the next level to go to.  It's not a big deal in the beginning, but the game will have around 5000 words upon launch and so it seems like a lot of unnecessary looping!

So far, I can see 2 ways to handle this:

1. On Start, I could loop through all 4 levels of the organizational structure and generate a flat List of Words.  Then it would be trivial to increment through the Words.
2. I could create a backend button and if I click on it, it would loop through all 4 levels of the organizational structure and generate a flat List of words.  It would then Save that list, so that it doesn't have to be generated upon runtime each time.

But both of these approaches feel a bit kludge-y to me.  The first one would run every time the program is run, and the second one would require me to remember to re-bake a new flat List of Words every time I add a new one.

Is there a more elegant way I could be storing/incrementing through the Word Puzzles?  Thanks!

Comment: It may be a bit klunky, but a loop with a count of 5000 is not really a problem. If all the loop is doing is making a reference flat list (and not loading all words), just do it and come back at the end to a more refined version. But probably by that time you will find out your time might be better spent to implement another feature. If the user does not notice long loading times, he does not care how a level is loaded. Custom user levels are loaded by a different structure anyway most likely

Comment: How to use both options at the same time? Use Option 2 for convenience during development and Option 1 for performance during release.